# toolbar,phtml file need to show in another page(splash page list)

Tags: magento, splash-screen

I want to show my toolbar.phtml file in other page like splash-page. I just copy `<?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml(); ?>` from list.phtml file and put it into my splash-page view.phtml file.. also I have checked that the attripute-splash.xml file. there toolbar.phtml file is already placed. like :
`<block type="attributeSplash/page_view_product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                            <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        </block>
                        <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                    </block>`
but it's not showing into splashpage..
Kindly help..